# Grammaticality of “several of them she did not deem good enough, but there was one which”

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns

I'd like to know if the first proposition is grammatical in the following sentence

> **Several of them she did not consider good enough**, but there was one [that was outstanding].

Or should it necessarily be phrased as follows?

> There were several of them that she did not consider good enough, but …

Answer (score 4):

That sentence is grammatical — the object has been moved to the front, as more prominent information. This is done for emphasis or stylistic reasons. The unmarked sentence would read:

> She did not consider several of them good enough, but there was one that was outstanding.

---

Dans mon français de base:

L'objet a été déplacé au début, afin de rendre l'information plus visible. On fait cela pour des raisons de style ou d'emphase. La phrase sans nuance particulière serait celle que je propose ci-dessus.

Comment: Can you clarify/reword "to be a marked Theme"? Also, it might help this answer if you were to explore whether or not "to be" has been elided and any grammatical implications of that. "She did not consider several of them **to be** good enough."  Two other options would be ***as*** or ***as being***.  Perhaps someone else can comment, as I know not the answer, but only the question.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis I've edited to clarify Theme, but I'm not sure that adding more where it's not needed is necessarily a good idea. I don't think that assuming elision is wise in this case, since I have no qualms with the clause without __as (being)__.